# Unable to change text and text color of navigationitem's back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

I am trying to set the backbutton text color (to red) of my navbar using the code below. (NOTE: The code below is already in the 'previous' view controller, in this case in the 'Popular' view controller:

```
//Customize Back button
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 40)];
UILabel *backButtonLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 40)];
backButtonLabel.text = @"back";
backButtonLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"cf212a"];
[backButtonView addSubview:backButtonLabel];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

However, I am not getting the effect I want. I am still getting the default white color text in the backbutton. The text is not changed to 'back' as well

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because the backbuttonitem is a uibarbuttonitem that will be seen on the next view controller which will be pushed on top of your current view controller and not of the current view controller.

If you want to set the backbutton of the current view like you are trying to do in your above code than just move the code to the view controller that is shown before it(below it in the stack.) so that when you push the view controller for which you want to show custom back button which was set in the previous view controller. This is because the back button belongs to the previous view controller that is gonna push your new view controller...

Comment: the code above is already added to the previous viewcontroller but I am still not able to change the back button. Is the way I am adding a custom view (backButtonView) correct?

Comment: you can try with a normal uibarbuttonitem and then go for custom view, see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that only the `title` property matters in the back button item; it is there to let you have a long title in the middle and a shorter title in the back button.

The easiest way to add a custom "back button" is to set `UINavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`; you'll have to set its target/action appropriately.

Comment: i have multiple view controllers which makes it extremely inefficient in customizing the 'back button' one by one. Further more, more than one view controller can call another view controller, how can I set the target/action in this case?

Comment: The target is "self" and the action is something that pops it off the nav controller, presumably. There are probably also hacky ways involving a category on UINavigationBar, but I wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a simple `UIViewController` subclass that adds a customizable back button that allows you to change text colors. It basically adds some `willAppear`/`willDisappear` logic to animate the back button the way the `UINavigationController` does while using the `leftBarButtonItem` property.

https://github.com/typeoneerror/BBCustomBackButtonViewController

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Using this you can change the color of all of the navigation buttons:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Replace redColor with the following to adjust the color of the buttons:

```
colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:144/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1.0// pick your color using this
```

Be sure to put this in the view controller that pushes. Not the view controller where you want to see this back button color.  Like Robin explained.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I found to set it globally or locally is

```
    [[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
         [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil] 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a good way to set back button's font and colors at global level. That's in the current iOS 5. For that I'm using typeoneerror's https://github.com/typeoneerror/BBCustomBackButtonViewController mentioned here.

However there is a good way to set Navigation Bar buttons' text and tint color properties at global level without destroying other button's and menus appearance. I'm using code like:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.75] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] titleLabel] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
```

In one of my projects. I'm calling it from `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```